# Recursive Count Inversions

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, count, divide-and-conquer

I was trying to implement "Counting Inversions" from divide and conq. section problem from Algorithm and Design Book by Kleinberg, because it seemed to me optimal. I however cannot spot what is my typo. Problem is to count number of inversions (i.e. number of times a[i] > a[j] for i < j), similar to https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/ctci-merge-sort/problem.

What I have:

```
unsigned int countInversions (const std::vector<int> & A){
    if (A.size() == 1){
        return 0;
    }
    std::size_t const middle = A.size()/2;
    unsigned int inversions = 0;

    std::vector<int> A_l(A.begin(), A.begin() + middle);
    inversions += countInversions(A_l);

    std::vector<int> A_r(A.begin() + middle, A.end());
    inversions += countInversions(A_r);

    unsigned int i=0, j=0;
    while (i < A_l.size() && j < A_r.size()){
        if (A_l[i] > A_r[j]){
            inversions += middle - i;
            j++;
        }
        else{
            i++;
        }
    }
    return inversions;
}
```

I am almost sure that it is possible to do it without extra vectors, but I wanted to first make at least this thing to work. I was trying to use debugger, but the recursion confused me a lot.

From the hackerrank, I see that {2 1 3 1 2} is returning me 3, while 4 is expected.

Comment: The algorithm described in *Algorithm Design* (and suggested by the title of that hackerrank problem) is a minor addition to merge-sort, where we also keep a running count. Your code has the counting part, but there is no sorting happening.

Comment: I see. Then, it seems that the vector cannot be constant

Comment: @IIK The signature of the function in the question is `long countInversions(vector<int> arr)` so it's assumed that you copy the vector and do what you please with it.